# Python pandas multiplying 4 columns with decimal values

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns containing decimal values which I have to multiply to create a 5 column with the answer.  For example

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
0.03   0.02   0.01   0.05
0.12   0.32   0.05   0.03
```

I tried multiplying using the following code:

```
df['col5'] = df['col1']*df['col2']*df['col3']*df['col4']
```

I am getting the values such as these:

```
3.600000e-06
1.701000e-04
```

I don't know how to read these.  I tried rounding of these numbers to 8 digits.

```
round(df['col5'], 8)
```

does not work.  However

```
round(df['col5'], 6)
```

works.  I want to derive a minimum of 8 decimal points.  Hence, I tried converting the column to a Decimal column using,

```
from decimal import Decimal
df['col5'] = df['col5'].apply(Decimal)
```

This works...but it provides with with very long string of decimal values, which I could not round off as I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

Instead I tried converting it to string with `format`:

```
df['col5'] = format(df['col5'], ".8f")
```

but getting the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
```

How do i multiply the 4 columns and retain the values in the 5th column upto 8 decimal points.

Comment: The value is correct, that's just how tiny numbers are printed, using exponential notation. It means `3.6 * 10**-6`, and it does that instead of printing lots of zeroes `0.0000036`

Comment: @barmar  yes...i understand that...however the user of this data wanted it in readable format even if it contains 7 zeros before a decimal number.  Thank you for your response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify pandas option to display the number of decimals you want :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5))
print(df)

pd.set_option('precision',10)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you...this really helped.